# Adding zero to non leaded zero datetime string regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the following datetime string `2020-5-1 1:2` I used the pattern `(\W)(\d{1})` to match any digit with length 1 i.e non zero leaded, `5,1,1,2`. [This demo](https://regex101.com/r/6NYGJG/1) shows that pattern succeeded to catch them in the group 2 for every match.

Using Javascript's String `replace` method, **I have tried to turn the datetime sample string to be `2020-05-01 01:02`**. In [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fenutaqoya/edit?js,console) that runs the following snippet:

```
var txt = '2020-5-1 1:2'
var output = [];
output[0] = txt.replace(/(\W)(\d{1})/gi,'0$1');
output[1] = txt.replace(/(\W)(\d{1})/gi,'0$2');
console.log(output);
// The output: ["20200-0-0 0:", "202005010102"]
```

In the first output's entry, it does unexpected behavior, instead of adding `0` to the match, it replaced it with `0`! How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Use `.replace(/(\W)(\d)/gi,'$10$2')` or `.replace(/\b\d\b/g,'0$&')`, you forgot about the second captured value.

Comment: btw, you can also try substitution on the same site https://regex101.com/r/6NYGJG/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The second regex works as a charm. Thank you, but what's `\b` and `&` in the solution? If you could to give account about them in an answer, I will be appreciated.

Comment: `$&` is a backreference to the whole match. `\b` is a word boundary. If you need specific details please let know via a comment below the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much it is a great informative answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only used a single placeholder in the replacement pattern, but in the regex pattern, you consumed two substrings with two capturing groups, so one is lost.

To add `0` before single digits you may use

```
txt.replace(/\b\d\b/g,'0$&')
txt.replace(/(^|\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g,'$10$2')
txt.replace(/(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)/g,'0$&')     // With the ECMAScript2018+
```

Here, `\b\d\b` matches a digit that is neither preceded nor followed with an ASCII letter, digit or `_`. The substitution is `0` and the whole match value, `$&`.

The `(^|\D)(\d)(?!\d)` pattern capture start of string or a non-digit char into Group 1, then a digit is captured in Group 2. Then, `(?!\d)` makes sure there is no digit immediately to the right. The substitution is `$10$2`, Group 1 value, `0` and then Group 2 value.

The `(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)` pattern matches any digit not enclosed with other digits, and the substitution is the same as in Case 1.

JS demo:

```js
var txt = '2020-5-1 1:2';
console.log( txt.replace(/\b\d\b/g,'0$&') )
console.log( txt.replace(/(^|\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g,'$10$2') )
```